# Hierarchy permissions in Django

Tags: python, django

Please suggest me the best way. I am developing a Django application, you will have 3 types of User: Administrator, Reseller and User. They must have hierarchy. The administrator can see everything. The dealer can see everything that its users did. The User only sees what he did.

How can I make these permissions with hierarchy?

Comment: look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/

Comment: @HasanRamezani Why use an external package when you can easily handle it with native Django? And with 14 stars on the repo, and the last update since 4 years, bad idea...

Comment: @DavidW. External packages do a lot of heavy lifting for you.  I'll agree that django-hierarchical-auth doesn't seem to be mature or stable enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with 2 differents ways:

- First solution (seems to be better in your case): using Django [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization)

Here you're gonna create groups, permissions and users. A good practice is to link permissions to groups, and then to link your users to groups. This way, it's easy to change something in the future.

- Second solution: create 3 different profiles that inherits from the User base class. It will be more complicated to handle thought.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar.  Per-line authorizations are a bit of a pain in Django.  There are two projects out there that can achieve all you are asking for: [django-permission](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission) and [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian).  I needed more finely grained permissions and had to roll my own.